# SDL Web 8.5 slowness with Safari

Tags: cme, web8.5

We are using SDL Web 8.5 and while it is working great so far, recently we have been receiving slowness issues when trying to Open/Save components and publishing.

We further investigated the issue and found the issue is with only `Safari 11.1.2` on `Sierra 10.12.6` whereas the CME is performing well with `Chrome` and `Firefox` latest version.

I can imagine this as a Safari browser issue since the version 11.1.2 launched couple of weeks ago.

So my question: did anyone else experience the same and more importantly, is there any hotfix (public or non-public) available for the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this indeed does sound like a browser update caused issue and as such, the best course of action would be to contact SDL support to ask for a hotfix. Even if there isn't one at the moment, you contacting them will bring this issue into their attention so they can address it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will be checking with SDL support soon